# Addition to equally substituted carbons

Tags: organic-chemistry, c-c-addition

I was wondering whether there is a trick in the following problem:

> [image]

Since both carbons are equally substituted, shouldn't the products be the same with or without the use 
of peroxides?

Comment: Equally substituted but not equal enviroments. The Ph group makes a significant difference to the stability of both radicals and cations. This will result in regioselectivity for both reactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of HBr with peroxide leads to an anti-Markonikov's product(known as the peroxide effect).The carbons are both substituted once, but not equally! One has a methyl group while the other side has a phenyl group. The chemical basis for the Markovnikov's  rule is the formation of a a stable carbocation during the addition process.

So, with just HBr a nomal Markovnikov's addition takes place i.e the Br group gets attached adjacent to the phenyl group while the H on the next carbon(as a benzylic carbocation is more stable).Final product: Ph-CHBr-CH2-CH3.
With the peroxide however , the opposite happens leading to the formation if Ph-CH2-CHBr-CH3.